# Self-inlining python code. (Now with MCVE!)

Tags: python, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have a program written in python where the user supplies command-line parameters to say which stats, in which combinations, should be processed on some data.

Initially I wrote code that would take N stats in X combinations and calculate the results - however, I found that if I wrote the code for myself to do that specific combination of stats it would always be much much faster. I then wrote code that will write the python I would have written if I had done it by hand, and exec()ute it, and this works perfectly well. Ideally, I would like to find a way to get the same performance as when python re-writes the loop, but doing it in some way that doesn't require all my functions to be strings!!

The following code is a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example to show the problem.

```
import time
import argparse
import collections

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    description="Demonstration that it is sometimes much faster to use exec() than to not.")
parser.add_argument("--stat", nargs='+', metavar='', action='append',
    help='Supply a list of stats to run here. You can use --stat more than once to make multiple groups.')
args = parser.parse_args()

allStats = {}
class stat1:
    def __init__(self):
        def process(someValue):
            return someValue**3
        self.calculate = process
allStats['STAT1'] = stat1()

class stat2:
    def __init__(self):
        def process(someValue):
            return someValue*someValue
        self.calculate = process
allStats['STAT2'] = stat2()

class stat3:
    def __init__(self):
        def process(someValue):
            return someValue+someValue
        self.calculate = process
allStats['STAT3'] = stat3()

allStatsString = {}
allStatsString['STAT1'] = 'STAT1 = someValue**3'
allStatsString['STAT2'] = 'STAT2 = someValue*someValue'
allStatsString['STAT3'] = 'STAT3 = someValue+someValue'

stats_to_run = set()                                                   # stats_to_run is a set of the stats the user wants to run, irrespective of grouping.
data = [collections.defaultdict(int) for x in range(0,len(args.stat))] # data is a list of dictionaries. One dictionary for each --stat group.
for group in args.stat:
    stats_to_run.update(group)
    for stat in group:
        if stat not in allStats.keys():
            print "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that."; exit()

loops = 9000000
option = 1
startTime = time.time()
if option == 1:
    results = dict.fromkeys(stats_to_run)
    for someValue in xrange(0,loops):
        for analysis in stats_to_run:
            results[analysis] = allStats[analysis].calculate(someValue)
        for a, analysis in enumerate(args.stat):
            data[a][tuple([ results[stat] for stat in analysis ])] += 1

elif option == 2:
    for someValue in xrange(0,loops):
        STAT1 = someValue**3
        STAT2 = someValue*someValue
        STAT3 = someValue+someValue        
        data[0][(STAT1,STAT2)] += 1  # Store the first result group
        data[1][(STAT3,)] += 1       # Store the second result group

else:
    execute = 'for someValue in xrange(0,loops):'
    for analysis in stats_to_run:
        execute += '\n    ' + allStatsString[analysis]
    for a, analysis in enumerate(args.stat):
        if len(analysis) == 1: 
            execute += '\n    data[' + str(a) + '][('+ analysis[0] + ',)] += 1'
        else: 
            execute += '\n    data[' + str(a) + '][('+ ','.join(analysis) + ')] += 1'
    print execute
    exec(execute)

## This bottom bit just adds all these numbers up so we get a single value to compare the different methods with (to make sure they are the same)
total = 0
for group in data:
    for stats in group:
        total += sum(stats)
print total
print time.time() - startTime
```

If the script is executed with the parameters `python test.py --stat STAT1 STAT2 --stat STAT3`, then on average:

- Option 1 takes 92 seconds
- Option 2 takes 56 seconds
- Option 3 takes 54 seconds (not surprising as it is basically the same as above).

  If the parameters become more complex, such as "--stat STAT1 --stat STAT2 --stat STAT3 --stat STAT1 STAT2 STAT3" or the number for loops goes up, the gap between the self-inlined code and the regular python code becomes wider and wider and wider:
- Option 1 takes 393s
- Option 3 takes 190s

  Typically my users would do 50 to 100 million loops, with probably 3 groups with 2 to 5 stats per group. The stats themselves are not trivial there, but the difference in calculation time is hours.

Comment: "So my question is - how do I get python to be as efficient as if it were to re-write it's code to do the least amount of work?"  Any chance you could translate that into English?  What do mean "to re-write its code"?  Python doesn't write code, a programmer writes code.

Comment: In the example above, python executes some code it wrote itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just trying to avoid repeated computations of the same statistics. Try this. Note that I'm using `docopt`, and so I use comma-delimited lists. You have already figured it out somehow, but don't show us how, so don't worry about that - it's not important. The code in `parse_args` where I build a set of stat names is probably the key thing.

```
"""
Usage: calcstats (--analyses <STAT>,...) ... <file> ...

Options:
    <file>                    One or more input filenames
    -a,--analyses <STAT> ...  One or more stat names to compute

"""

import docopt
import time

_Sequence = 0
_Results = {}

def compute_stat(name):
    global _Sequence, _Results

    print("Performing analysis: {}".format(name))
    time.sleep(1)
    _Sequence += 1
    _Results[name] = _Sequence

def display_results(groups):
    global _Results

    groupnum = 1
    for grp in groups:
        print("*** Group {}:".format(groupnum))
        for stat in grp:
            print("\t{}: {}".format(stat, _Results[stat]))
        print("\n")

def parse_args():
    args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    args['--analyses'] = [stat.split(',') for stat in args['--analyses']]

    stat_set = set()
    stat_set.update(*args['--analyses'])
    args['STATS.unique'] = stat_set

    return args

def perform_analyses(stat_set):
    for stat in stat_set:
        compute_stat(stat)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    perform_analyses(args['STATS.unique'])
    display_results(args['--analyses'])
```

Comment: wow docopt is awesome! I've never seen that before. Took me a while to figure out where it was even getting its data from :P
So yeah, your code is a conciser version of my full script, which does the set making as you show. It actually makes a list so that modules dependant on each other are run in the right order (but its 800 lines long so i left all that out). The code i posted is just the perform_analyses() part of your script. I added a little comment into your code to show that the stat_set iteration, and looking up of the stat method, happens for every line in my input data....

Comment: ....which is what is slowing things down. If i define my compute_stat() functions as strings, and build a loop from strings and exec()ute it, then it takes 1.5minutes of the total execution time. Thats the issue. I want my program to be as fast as possible, but storing functions as strings and building properly-indented code seems like a silly way to optimise some code.

Comment: Based on your answer Austin, I have re-written the question to include a MCVE instead of the code from my actual project. I hope things are clearer now :D

Comment: @J.J I'm a little confused by your example and your comments above. It sounds like you are deciding what to compute on a line-by-line basis. Is this true?

Comment: What to compute is decided by the user arguments, but the only way to put whatever that logic is into the program is to have something in the line-by-line loop that finds the required functions, and gets results. However, if you were to write the script specifically for that combination of user arguments, you wouldn't need to "find" the functions for every line. You'd just write them in like in option 2. In option 3 that is done automatically by python itself.

Comment: I'm seeing that. I'm also seeing that you do some weird stuff under the label "store the ... result group". I'm surprised by that, since I figured it could wait until after the loop. You've mentioned that the stats collection code is large, which should argue against spending time doing this sort of optimization. How is the code organized otherwise? It sounds like you're getting about 10,000 iterations per second, which implies a lot of code being run. But if there's a lot of code, the time spend in dispatch should be negligible...

Comment: I just put the code up on Github tonight, so you can look at the full example if you like! This is all happening on line  870-900. However, its a pretty domain-specific program. I doubt it will be much fun :I But if you run the example above that works too.

Comment: Is there a url to go with that?

Comment: Ah, sorry sorry, Im an idiot - here it is: https://github.com/JohnLonginotto/SeQC/blob/master/SeQC.js.py

Comment: Okay, right off the bat I think you need to convert your `.before` strings to methods. There is no reason to treat them as strings and all that noise - they're only run once.

Comment: Also, you should probably define a parent class for the stats, so they can inherit trivial/no-op `.before` and `.after` methods.

Comment: I've added a bunch of issues on GH.